# AppleScript variables in sed string

Tags: bash, sed, applescript

I am by no means an AppleScript expert, but get by. I am running into a hell of a time trying to pass some AppleScript variables to a `sed` command in order to replace some text in a file, based on the variables.

I have two dialog boxes in AppleScript that grab user data, and I store those variables. `myData` - This works OK.

```
set myData to text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Enter Your Data" with title ¬
        "Data Entry" default answer ¬
        "" buttons {"Continue…"} ¬
        default button 1 ¬
        ) 

set searchFor to quoted form of "data1"
set searchFor2 to quoted form of "data2"
set inputFile to "/Users/User1/Desktop/file.txt"
set outputFile to "/Users/User1/Desktop/file1.txt"

do shell script quoted form of ("sed -i.bak s/" & searchFor & "/" & myData & "/g") & " " & inputFile & " > " & outputFile
```

I actually get this error: `No such file or directory`,  exit code `127`. The weird part is, though, that it does write out the file with zero data in it. I am not necessarily trying to write out a diff file as the script suggests, just edit data in place. However, I've had zero success that way, which is why I approached it this way.

Any assistance with my issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Your **immediate issues** are that **you mistakenly apply `quoted form of` *multiple* times**, and, more to the point,  **apply `quoted form of` to the `sed` executable name, its options, and the `sed` script *together*, which invariably breaks** (see below for a detailed explanation); try the following - *without* applying `quoted form of` to any of the variables *beforehand* - note how `quoted form of` is applied *selectively* to the `sed` *script* and the in- and output files, respectively:

```applescript
do shell script "sed " & quoted form of ¬
  ("s/" & searchFor & "/" & myData & "/g") ¬
  & " " & quoted form of inputFile & " > " & quoted form of outputFile
```

<sup>Note that I've removed `-i.bak` from your command, because it would invariably result in an *empty* output file: `-i` updates the input file *in place*, producing *no stdout output*. Thus, *nothing* would be sent to `outputFile` with `> outputFile`.</sup>

However, this **can still break or misbehave, if `searchFor` and `myData` contain either `/` or characters that have special meaning in a `sed` regular expression** (e.g., `\`, `*`, `[`, ...) or **replacement string** (e.g., `&`, `\`).

To avoid that, you'll have to *escape* the input strings first, which is non-trivial, unfortunately.

The following **handlers** **provide robust, generic escaping** - they are based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375), where the underlying commands are explained<sup>[1]</sup>) :

```
# Quotes (escapes) a string for safe use in a `sed` regex.
on quoteRegex(txt)

    do shell script "sed -e 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\\^/\\\\^/g; $!a\\'$'\\n''\\\\n' <<<" & quoted form of txt & " | tr -d '\\n'"

end quoteRegex

# Quotes (escapes) a string for safe use in a `sed` substitution string (`s///` function).
on quoteSubst(txt)

    do shell script "IFS= read -d '' -r <<<\"$(sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}' -e 's/[&/\\]/\\\\&/g; s/\\n/\\\\&/g' <<<" & quoted form of txt & "; printf X)\"; printf %s \"${REPLY%$'\\n'X$'\\n'}\"" without altering line endings

end quoteSubst
```

<sup>[1] Some tweaks were necessary to make them work with `do shell script`; notably, process substitution (`<(...)`) is not supported; the workaround via `<<<"$(...)"` necessitated extra steps to accurately preserve trailing newlines in the input.</sup>

Once you've pasted above handlers into your script, here's how to apply them to your command:

```
do shell script "sed " & quoted form of ¬
  ("s/" & my quoteRegex(searchFor) & "/" & my quoteSubst(myData) & "/g") ¬
  & " " & quoted form of inputFile & " > " & quoted form of outputFile
```

---

As for you **original symptoms**:

> The weird part is, though, that it does write out the file with zero data in it.

This indicates that `do shell script` (a) was able to invoke the shell, (b) the shell parsed the command line without encountering a syntax error; if these conditions are met, an output redirection such as `> outFile` causes the target file to *created* as a zero-byte file, or, if it existed, to truncate it to a zero-byte file, BEFORE command execution begins.

If command execution then fails, the zero-byte file is left behind.

> I actually get this error: No such file or directory, exit code 127

Exit code `127` indicates that the executable that is the 1st token of your command string could not be invoked, because it could not be found.

This is indeed what happened, because you mistakenly applied `quoted form of` to the `sed` executable name, its options, and the `sed` script *together*, which causes the *entire* resulting string to be interpreted as the executable name, which obviously fails.

Let's take a simplified example:

```
quoted form of "sed s/foo/bar/g file"
```

yields `'sed s/foo/bar/g file'`, *including* the enclosing single quotes.
Passing this string to the shell causes the shell to consider this string a *single* token that constitutes the *executable path or filename*. Obviously, no file named `sed s/foo/bar/g file` exists, so the command fails.

The solution, as demonstrated above, is to pass `sed`, its options, the script, as well as the input filename and the output filename as *separate* tokens.

Comment: Hello , Thanks for your help. I tried to Apply it to the script However I now I get an error saying.. "error "«script» doesn’t understand the “quoteRegex” message." number -1708 from «script»"  Is it perhaps because this is Mac OS X?

Comment: @cybersurfr: Glad to help; the error message implies that you haven't defined the `on quoteRegex ... end quoteRegex` (and probably also `on quoteSubst ...`) handlers from above (2nd snippet). Put them in the same script and try again.

Comment: *facepalm* @PeterSmith Yep, you were right on that account. Once I added them in like this " on quoteRegex(txt)
 do shell script "sed -i.bak " & quoted form of ¬
  ("s/" & my quoteRegex(searchFor) & "/" & my quoteSubst(myData) & "/g") ¬
   & " " & quoted form of inputFile & " > " & quoted form of outputFile
end quoteRegex"     It would give "" in the result window , but nothing was changed and the outputfile would not be created

Comment: @cybersurfr: No, you have to define the handlers _as posted_, _separately_ from your `do shell script` command. They are _helper_ functions (handlers). As an aside: if a script contains a handler _definition only_ and no code to _invoke_ it, _nothing_ will happen.

Comment: Gotcha, I added the handlers and that fixed the issue of not getting the output file. I then added the    do shell script "sed -i.bak " & quoted form of ¬
 ("s/" & my quoteRegex(searchFor) & "/" & my quoteSubst(myData) & "/g") ¬
  & " " & quoted form of inputFile & " > " & quoted form of outputFile   However Now this results in an empty output file instead.

Comment: @cybersurfr: There's a problem with the `sed` command itself: you must remove `-i.bak` to get output sent to `outputFile` (see updated answer), or, alternatively, remove the `> outputFile` part and have `-i` update the input file _in place_.

Comment: That time, was so close it nearly made me cry. I get the correct output file. It contains everything in the original file. however no replacement has taken place. Do you think I would have more success by replacing the (searchfor)  in ("s/" & my quoteRegex(searchFor) with a hard coded value? I can do that, I just wanted it to be more flexible.

Comment: @cybersurfr: In [Apple]Script Editor, make the log pane visible (`View > Show Log`), click on `Events`, run the script, then look at the _last_ `do shell script` line, which will say something like `do shell script "sed 's/[f][o][o]/bar/g' '/Users/User1/Desktop/file.txt' > '/Users/User1/Desktop/file1.txt'"` - this is what AppleScript sends to the shell. Take the command _between_ the double quotes and experiment with it directly in the shell, in a Terminal window, until it works as intended. Then work your way backwards.

Comment: Symbol `¬`, how to type it under Mac OS X and Windows? It doesn't seem to be in ASCII, I lookup, some say it's Extended Ascii 170 [Ref 1](http://www.alt-codes.net/), [Ref 2](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/logical-negation-symbol-ascii-code-170.html), is it `Option/Alt` + `L`? (I compare it with the `¬` character in the answer, it match.), can you verify?

Comment: @mklement0, Thanks, I remember that in AppleScript Editor, press `Option+Return` to get `¬`, anywhere else, `Option` + `L` will work (including AppleScript Editor). I just tried `Alt + 0  1 7 0` (Numeric keypad) on Windows, and it get this `ª`, it looks like an superscript `a`, but, it do not have a strike under it (StackOverflow might did something), certainly not `¬`.

Comment: @Albert Thanks for the feedback; don't know what I was smoking earlier: I got the decimal form of the Unicode codepoint wrong; let me try again: Yes, it is Unicode `0xac` (`172`), the so-called NOT SIGN. (The only thing to add to your helpful comment about the Mac keyboard shortcuts is that they won't work in Terminal). On Windows, try `Alt + 0 1 7 2` _on the numeric keypad_ (hold down Alt and type these four digits; unverified).

Comment: @mklement0 Well, that `Alt` + `0 1 7 2` works on Windows! About terminal, the Mac shortcut I mentioned works fine on my Mac terminals (OS X 10.9.5), both Terminal v2.4 and iTerm2 Build 2.1.1, also works on Text Editor, Stickies, Finder, Evernote, etc., I don't know if I did something.

Comment: @Albert: Thanks again for the feedback. It was _I_ who did something: if you turn on `Use Option as Meta key` in the profile used by Terminal (via the `Profiles` tab in Terminal's Preferences, anchor `Keyboard`), `Option-L` does _not_ work - by default it does.

Comment: @mklement0 Agreed, finally, this `¬` issue met its closure.